# Percentile_disc to obtain Median - I don't want to use AVG,MIN,SUM,MAX

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, median

This is my code to calculate the median:

```
select distinct srt.Name,

    cast(sum(sr.price) as int) as AvgCost,cast(sum(sr.cost) as int) as 

    AvgTransCost,cast(avg(sr.TotalTimeSpent) as int) as TotalTimeSpent,

    percentile_disc(.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY avg(sr.price)) OVER(PARTITION BY srt.Name)    AS MedianSpend
```

on this line:

```
percentile_disc(.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY avg(sr.price)) OVER(PARTITION BY srt.Name)    AS MedianSpend
```

I am unable to change it to:

```
(ORDER BY (sr.price))
```

If I try to run the code without the AVG infront of (sr.price), I receive this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jfS0.jpg

How can I run it without adding AVG,SUM,MIN,MAX before (sr.price) ??

Comment: What happens if you run it with only the `percentile_disc` in your select, getting rid of the other columns?

Comment: it runs fine when I exclude everything except percentile_disc! it also works when I add AVG,MIN,SUM,MAX before (sr.price), its that I am unable to run it without one of those.